# How to make monaco-editor auto fit content like codemirror auto resize mode?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

The codemirror editor support a mode that auto fit height with it's content:

http://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html

Can we make monaco-edtior auto fit content too?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** add `automaticLayout: true` to your editor configuration:

```
 monaco.editor.create( domEl, {...options, automaticLayout: true});
```

Your question is the general question of [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017753/monaco-editor-dynamically-resizable/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using Monaco to provide a nicely rendered view of static code snippets in what is essentially documentation.  So, I don't need for my Monaco editor instances to adapt and resize to changing content, and I'm not particularly concerned about them being responsive to changing browser windows.  I just need them to render their snippets completely, no more no less, on first load and without scroll bars; little snippets in little editor windows and larger snippets in larger ones.

For whatever reason, all my attempts to use `automaticLayout: true` for this purpose never worked.  I also didn't have any luck with the various suggestions to call `editor.layout()`.  I only ever got editors that were around 10px tall.  I worked around this by creating a wrapper component for monaco-editor/react that set the height of the editor based on the scroll bar height after the editor is mounted.

```typescript
import * as React from "react";
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { Monaco } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { editor } from "monaco-editor";

export interface IMonacoWrapperProps {
  content: string;
  options?: editor.IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions;
  className?: string;
}

export function MonacoWrapper(props: IMonacoWrapperProps): JSX.Element {
  const [editorHeight, setEditorHeight] = React.useState(0);

  function editorDidMount(
    editor: editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor,
    monaco: Monaco
  ) {
    const scrollHeight = editor.getScrollHeight();
    setEditorHeight(scrollHeight);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Editor
        height={editorHeight}
        defaultLanguage="typescript"
        defaultValue={props.content}
        options={props.options}
        onMount={editorDidMount}
        className={props.className}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a link to a demo of this in CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autosize-monaco-editor-to-content-on-first-load-dwvxlv?file=/src/MonacoWrapper.tsx

Comment: Works Fine. i like the way you think about this Problem. did you find any way to increase the monacoEditor Height after the content changed and some lines were added?

Comment: Thanks!  In my scenario, my content is static so dynamic resizing after the first render just isn't a problem that I have to deal with so it's not something I've looked into.  Sorry :(

Just peeking into the Monaco API documentation, it looks like there are keyboard and content events so maybe you could hook into those and then call a resizing function like the one I've got in `editorDidMount`.  If your content changes from an external source, then maybe you could watch for those changes and call a resizing function then.

Comment: Thanks for your Guide. I got some Solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who might need to resize its Editor Layout based on the Lines.

First of all, you should Specify some **lineHeight** in the monacoEditor options.

After that you can listen to onChange event of Monaco editor and get the lines Count by this method **getLineCount** and set it to your editor height State.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Editor } from "@monaco-editor/react";

const EditorIDE = () => {
  const ideRef = useRef(null);

  const [editorHeight, setEditorHeight] = useState(null);

  const handleMountIde = (editor, monaco) => {
    // first time you set the height based on content Height
    ideRef.current = editor;
    const contentHeight =
      editor.getContentHeight() > 100 ? editor.getContentHeight() : 420;
    setEditorHeight(contentHeight);
  };

  const handleChange = (value, e) => {
    setEditorHeight(ideRef.current.getModel().getLineCount() * 19);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        height={editorHeight}
        defaultLanguage="javascript"
        defaultValue={''}
        theme="vs-dark"
        onMount={handleMountIde}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={{
          automaticLayout: true,
          roundedSelection: true,

          // Set Line Height
          lineHeight: 19,

          scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default EditorIDE;
```